# VTKImagedata argument is incompatible with VTKAlgorithmOutput

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vtk, itk

I'm trying to give an image input to itk and then it being passed to vtk for it to be displayed as an output. However,when dealing with the VTKImagedata function, it gives me this compilation error. 
Any idea on how to pass this argument sucessfully?

Thanks in advance.

[Code and Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa8pW.png)

Comment: At StackOverflow we don't want pictures for either of the code and error. Copy and paste the text from your IDE. Since you are using Visual Studio get the error message from the Output Tab. That is in a better format than the errors tab for copy / paste as text.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, will update the info!

Comment: If you are using `SetInputConnection` on the viewer, you cannot use `GetOutput`. Perhaps `GetOutputPort` would be more adequate here.